# Android back button navigate to specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the navigation drawer menu structure presently setup to allow for going back to the previous fragmnet, with addToBackStack, when selecting the back button as:

```
    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_messages) {
            FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new MessageTabFragment()).addToBackStack("MainActivity").commit();
        }
```

However, I wish to allow for the back button to always send the user back to a specific framgment, not simply the previous one.

How can this be accomplished?

**amended**

I attempted adding the code:

```
int homeFragmentIdentifier = -1;
```

`...`

```
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_messages) {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                if(homeFragmentIdentifier == -1) {
                    homeFragmentIdentifier = xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new MessageTabFragment()).commit();
                } else {
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new MessageTabFragment()).commit();
                }

            }
```

`...`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    getFragmentManager().popBackStack(homeFragmentIdentifier, 0);

}
```

But it simply calls the error:

```
01-15 19:31:55.368 18410-18410/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.android.feastappv2, PID: 18410
                                                   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad id: -1
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStack(FragmentManager.java:526)
                                                       at com.example.android.feastappv2.feastapp.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:143)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2667)
                                                       at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3214)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2922)
```

Comment: You still have to call `xfragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(String)` or `commit()` will always return -1.

Answer (score 19):

Take a look at this:
[FragmentManager.popBackStack(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(int,%20int))

When you commit your fragment transaction, the method returns an identifier for that transaction.  Save that `int` identifier:

```
FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beingTransaction();
xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new MessageTabFragment());
xfragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("MainActivity");
int homeFragmentIdentifier = transaction.commit();
```

then, in your `onBackPressed()` method, you can add either of the following lines:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(homeFragmentIdentifier, 0); // Exclusive
```

or

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack("MainActivity", 0); // Exclusive
```

This will pop the back stack all the way back to the supplied identifier. Alternatively, if you want to include the `homeFragmentIdentifier` in the "pop"ing, instead of `0` use `FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE` for the 2nd parameter. 
You still must call `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack()`.  According to the docs:

> public abstract int commit () ...
>   Returns the identifier of this transaction's back stack entry, if addToBackStack(String) had been called. Otherwise, returns a negative number.

Also, if you set the tag of the fragment when adding it to the backstack, for example:

```
transaction.add(yourFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack("[YourFragmentTransactionTag]");
```

You can use the alternate method: [FragmentManager.popBackStack(String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(String,%20int)) by supplying the tag you used when adding the transaction to the backstack.

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack("[YourFragmentTransactionTag]", 0);
```

Comment: Where do I place the `onBackPressed()` method?

Comment: `onBackPressed()` can be overridden in your activity.

Comment: but when a user navigates to a fragment, the call to `onBackPressed()` will be accepted?

Comment: Yes, a fragment is created inside an activity, so that method will work. All you have to do is reference the fragment manager from that method and tell it to pop the back stack.

Comment: I attempted what you noted, but it did not function

Comment: Sorry, in both cases, you still need to call `xfragmentTransaction.addToBackStack()`. `FragmentTransaction.commit()` will always return -1 if you don't call it. I updated my answer.